# Find the value attribute of an active button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a simple calculation based on a few inputs, however I am unable to get the value from the currently active HTML button class using Javascript.

The code loops through the buttons and adds the active class to the current/clicked button. I then want the calculation to be based off the value of that active button.

The variable "rating" returns undefined.

What would be the correct way to do this?

HTML:

```
   <div class="finance-calc">
       <div class="finance-entry">
           <h1 class="title">Finance calculator</h1>
           <div class="finance-inputs">
               <div class="amount">
                   <h4>I'd like to borrow</h4>
                   <input id="finance-amount-input" type="text">
               </div>
               <div class="term">
                   <h4>Over a period of</h4>
                   <select name="term" id="finance-term-input">
                       <option value="12">12 months</option>
                       <option value="24">24 months</option>
                       <option value="36">36 months</option>
                       <option value="48">48 months</option>
                   </select>
               </div>
           </div>
           <h2 class="rating">Rating</h2>
           <div id="finance-options">
               <button id="excellent" value="2" class="btn active">Excellent</button>
               <button id="good" value="1.13" class="btn">Good</button>
               <button id="average" value="1.14" class="btn">Average</button>
               <button id="bad" value="1.15" class="btn">Bad</button>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="finance-output">
           <div id="result"></div>
           <div id="total-payable">Total payable: £5420</div>
           <button id="calculate" value="10">Calculate</button>
           <button class="apply-btn">Apply Now</button>
       </div>
   </div>
```

JS:

```
// Get the container element
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("finance-options");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}

// Calculate button
const calculate = document.getElementById("calculate");

// Button click calculates monthly payment
calculate.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const amount = document.getElementById("finance-amount-input").value;
  const term = document.getElementById("finance-term-input").value;
  const rating = document.getElementsByClassName("active").value; // i want this line to find the value attribute of the active button

  const loan = (amount * rating) / term;

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "£" + loan.toFixed(2) + " PCM";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

- `document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0]`

or:

- `document.querySelector('.active')`